# Using time as an coordinate in nvD3 plots

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, nvd3.js

I am trying to plot an array of values on a line plot. The values each have a date/time stamp.
So an example data point is:

```
aPoint = { 'label': 201401082015, //so this corresponds to 2014, Jan 08th, at 10:15PM
          'data' : 1234
         };
```

How do I convert `label` into a form that nvd3 can recognise as a date/time? By not changing the form of `label`, incorrect spacing between data points will occur (due to 60 minutes in 1 hour, 24 hours in 1 day and not 100).

To elaborate, if an event occurs at `23:00` hrs (11pm), and another at `01:00` hrs (1am) the following day, then in reality these events are 2 hours apart. Incorrectly however, they will be plotted as if they are 78 hours (101-23=78) apart due to hours in a day not being `base 10`.

How do I convert `label` into a form that nvd3 can recognise as a date/time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I convert label into a form that nvd3 can recognize as a
>   date/time?

Like this:

```
function labelToMs(label){
  var parts = label.toString().match(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);
  var partsToInt = parts.slice(0,5).map(function(s){return parseInt(s)});
  var date = new Date(partsToInt[0], partsToInt[1]-1, partsToInt[2], partsToInt[3], partsToInt[4]);
  return date.getTime();
}
```

This function will return a number that won't have that issue, because it will be the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Also, if you have an Array of points and you want to convert it to an Array with the label as the number of MS, you could do it like this:

```
var yourArrayOfPoints = yourArrayOfPoints.map(function(point){ 
  point.label = labelToMs(point.label);
  return point;
});
```